# How to convert this particular expression into some desired form?

Tags: trigonometry, derivatives, parametric

The parametric equations of a curve are
$$x=\cos(t) \cdot e^{-t} $$
$$y=\sin(t) \cdot e^{-t} $$

Show that $dy/dx =tan(t-\pi/4) $.

how to solve this?
I can get a $dy/dx$ but i cannot convert into the desired form above.

This is the $dy/dx$ expression i get:

$dy/dx=\dfrac{Sin(t)-Cos(t))*-e^-t}{Sin(t)+Cos(t))*-e^-t}$

Edit:
I worked the required expression backwards and got the necessary clue which resulted in this:

$$ \frac{\frac{\sqrt2}{2}(\sin t -\cos t)}{\frac{\sqrt2}{2}(\cos t +\sin t)}$$
(thanks Pauly B)

Comment: maybe you mean $x=sin(t)\times e^{-t}$

Comment: and try using chain-rule

Comment: That part is done.I cant get the derivative into the desired expression

Comment: i post an answer, try reading :)

Comment: Normally $dy/dx$ is a function of $x$ but it's interesting that here it is a function of $t$.

Comment: You can cancel out the exponentials in your dy/dx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\begin{align}
\frac{dy}{dx}&=\frac{\sin t-\cos t}{\cos t+\sin t}\\
&=\frac{\sqrt2(\sin t \cos\frac\pi4-\cos t\sin\frac\pi4)}{\sqrt2(\cos t \cos\frac\pi4+\sin t\sin\frac\pi4)}\\
&=\frac{\sin(t-\frac\pi4)}{\cos(t-\frac\pi4)}\\
&=\tan(t-\frac\pi4)
\end{align}$$

Comment: That seems correct.though i am not sure why  $ \sqrt2$ is there in the 2nd expression.

Comment: This is the expression i made to get to the answer:$ \frac{\frac{\sqrt2}{2}(\sin t -\cos t)}{\frac{\sqrt2}{2}(\cos t +\sin t)}$

Answer (score 2):

Work backwards from the desired endpoint.  There's really only one thing to be done with $\tan(t-\frac\pi4)$, and that's applying the addition formula:
$$ \tan(t-\tfrac\pi4) = \frac{\tan(t)-\tan(\tfrac\pi4)}{1+\tan(t)\tan(\tfrac\pi4)} = \frac{\tan(t)-1}{1+\tan(t)} $$
What could you do next with this, to make it look more like $\frac{\sin(t)-\cos(t)}{\sin(t)+\cos(t)}$?

Answer (score 1):

$\textbf{Hint}$: $cos(t)^2+\sin(t)^2=1$, do $x^2+y^2$ and you will get a function $y$ who depends of $x$, then apply chain rule and dont forget the term $dx/dt$

Comment: oh, you dont need the part $dx/dt$, sorry, the rest is ok.